# Manage 2 or 3 functionalities on checked elements in a table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a page with a list of items (tabular presentation). On each line in this table, I have a checkbox. The user can check some elements and submit the form for adding these elements to his favorites. It works for this functionnality. Now I would like to add other functionalities like 'delete selected elements' or 'mail selected elements'. I don't know how to proceed... Any help will be highly appreciated.

Below is my view page:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("AddCheckedItemsToFavorites","Home",FormMethod.Post, new { id="form1" } )) { %>
    <table class="search-results">                                
        <% foreach (var affaire in Model.AffairePagingResult.Items) { %>
            <tr>
                <td class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="<%= affaire.IdAffaire%>" />
                </td>
                <td class="favoricon">
                    <%= Html.ImageFavorite(affaire) %>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <% } %>
    </table>
<% } %>
```

Below is my controller:

```
[Authorize, HttpPost] 
public ActionResult AddCheckedItemsToFavorites(string[] checkbox)
{
    if (checkbox != null)
    {
        foreach (string item in checkbox)
        {
             // do some stuff here
        }
    }
    // go back...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution as explained below. I trigger a specific button for each situation. In my controller, I can call a specific action. Thank you anyway.

My view page:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("ManageCheckedItems", "Home",FormMethod.Post)) { %>
    // manage checkbox or other stuff here in a table...                    
    <input type="submit" class="hidden-submit-button" name="submitFavor" />
    <input type="submit" class="hidden-submit-button" name="submitEmail" />
<% } %>
```

My jQuery script:

```
    $("#add-to-favorites").click(function () {
        $("input[name='submitFavor']").trigger('click');
    });

    $("#send-by-mail").click(function () {
        $("input[name='submitEmail']").trigger('click');
    });
```

My controller:

```
    [Authorize, HttpPost]
    public void ManageCheckedItems(string[] checkbox, string submitFavor, string submitEmail)
    {
        if (submitFavor != null) AddCheckedItemsToFavorite(checkbox);
        if (submitEmail != null) SendCheckedItemsByEmail(checkbox);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
Html.ActionLink("Add To Favorites", 
   new { controller = "Home", action = "AddCheckedItemsToFavorites", id = "form1" })
```

and

```
Html.ActionLink("Delete", 
       new { controller = "Home", action = "DeleteCheckedItems", id = "form1" })
```

instead of setting action to your form, just use a simple form tag

Comment: thank you for your reply. I try with an ActionLink exactly as you typed but I got an error because there is no signature with these arguments for ActionLink. So I try like this: Html.ActionLink("Add to favorites", "AddCheckedItemsToFavorites, "Home"). In this case it successfully compiled but on debugging the controller (after clicking the link) I didn't receive my checked items list because the form has not been submitted. So I think I really need submission of the form.

Comment: you can do a simple trick. add a javascript function witch gathers checked checkboxes list and stores it in a hidden text box. then in your action link pass its value as an argument to your action method. don't forget to create related route in your mvc application routes.

Comment: yes there are trick solutions but I really would like to be as clean as possible because I'm learning ASP.NET MVC and **it is important for me to follow guidance and best practice**. So I prefer to stay with a submitting solution of my form. Any ideas?